# How to fix "Conversion of string to delegate"

Tags: c#

I am writing a code snippet (strings) for test which contains a method in constructor, the parameters of the method are string and delegate. I have delegate placed in code snippet but while compiling the compiler doesn't recognize the second parameter as delegate but instead recognizes as method group.

I have tried casting the second parameter to delegate type

```
class Test : AbstractClassA
{                 
    public Test()   
    {
        Invoke("SomeString", MethodDelegate);
    }

    private void MethodDelegate(string a, string b)
    { 

    }
}


public abstract class AbstractClassA
{
    protected void Invoke(string a, string b)
    {

    }
}
```

`Invoke` has delegate as `MethodDelegate` as `delegate` in second parameter while the entire `string` (first code block) gets compiled, compiler has to recognize `MethodDelegate` as `delegate` but not as method group

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "Invoke has delegate as MethodDelegate as delegate in second parameter" - no, it has `string`: `protected void Invoke(string a, string b)`. I'm afraid it's really not clear to me what you're trying to do, but I would definitely try to write *regular C# code* to start with, that you just compile directly... you can then move to "compiling it on the fly" later on, once you've got working code *to* compile.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
protected void Invoke(string a, string b)
```

`Invoke` accepts 2 `string` parameters, not `delegate`, while you call it like `Invoke("SomeString", MethodDelegate);` - with one `string` and `Action<string, string>` as second parameter. Probably, you tried something like this:

```
class Test : AbstractClassA
{                 
    public Test()   
    {
        Invoke("SomeString", MethodDelegate);  // note, we passing only 1 string as parameter, so I changed MethodDelegate to accept only 1 string too
    }

    private void MethodDelegate(string a)
    { 

    }
}

public abstract class AbstractClassA {

    protected void Invoke(string a, Action<string> b)  // replaced second string with delegate
    {
        b(a);  // call passed action with passed parameter
    }
}
```